# PyMongo query documents that does not exist in another collection

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have 2 tables: `messages` and `responded_messages`

Both have a key called `message_id`.

I would like to to get all the documents from messages that are not in responded_messages based on the message_id. How would I do that in PyMongo?

For a python list example,

```
messages = [1,2,3]
responded_messages= [3]
```

The result should be `[1,2]`

I looked into the aggregation framework and feel it's something to do with that, but unable to point my finger on it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you're looking for is to perform `LEFT JOIN` between the two collections where `responded_messages` is `NULL`.

You can achieve this by using MongoDB aggregation pipeline [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator.

For example, given collection `messages` as below:

```
{ "_id": 1, "message_id": 1 }
{ "_id": 2, "message_id": 2 }
{ "_id": 3, "message_id": 3 }
```

and collection `responded_messages` as below:

```
{ "_id": 1, "message_id": 3 }
```

Using [PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/index.html), you can do:

```
collection = client["dbName"]["messages"]

pipeline = [{'$lookup': 
                {'from' : 'responded_messages',
                 'localField' : 'message_id',
                 'foreignField' : 'message_id',
                 'as' : 'responses'}
             },
             {'$match': {'responses' : {"$size": 0} } },
            ]

for doc in (collection.aggregate(pipeline)):
    print(doc)
```

See also [PyMongo Aggregation Examples](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html)